# Helmholtz coil: effective radius

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

A pair of Helmholtz coils is two coils with radius $R$ separated by $d=R$. But in a real world with coils consisting of many windings in a package of width $w$ and thickness $t$, what is $R$? Is it the inner radius $R_i$, the outer radius $R_o=R_i+t$ or the central radius $R_c = (R_i + R_o)/2$ of the coil winding package? Likewise, how do I need to measure the distance: between the innermost coil windings $d_i$, between the outermost $d_o = d_i+2w$ or between the center of those $d_c = (d_i + d_o)/2$?

My feeling is that it should be $R_c$ and $d_c$ but I can find only idealized calculations for one winding per coil.

Are the same considerations true if I use square coils? (using the factor 0.5445 for the distance to effective coil side length)

Comment: You can use Biot-Savart to calculate the field of a realistic coil. If your goal is a large homogeneous field volume field, then you would use e.g. a Maxwell coil or even higher order configurations to begin with rather than try to optimize the shape of the individual coil.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of Biot-Savart law and when I try to imagine it in my head the solution is to take the centers of the coils for the Helmholtz configuration.
Unfortunately, three coils as in a Maxwell coil configuration is not an option since there is no space in the center. However, I still would like to tweak out optimum homogeneity.

Comment: In that case I would probably try to nest multiple Helmholtz coils with one or a few turns each inside each other.